# Proving determinant value zero: $\det(M-I)=0$

Tags: matrices, determinant

If $M$ is a $3\times3$ matrix, where M'M=I and $\det(M)=1$, then prove that $\det(M-I)=0$

By the information given I know that given matrix is orthogonal. How can prove the above determinant zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $M^\prime M = I$, it follows that
$$
M - I = (I - M^\prime) M.
$$
Also, since $M$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\det(I - M^\prime)
&= \det\left(\left(I - M\right)^\prime\right)
= \det(I - M) \\
&= \det(-(M - I))
= \left(-1\right)^3 \det(M - I)
= -\det(M - I).
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore since $\det(M) = 1$,
$$
\det(M - I)
= \det(I - M^\prime) \det(M)
= \det(I - M^\prime)
= -\det(M - I).
$$
Thus, $\det(M - I) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

An orthogonal transformation of $\mathbb{R}^3$ has to be a rotation about some axis. So $M$ is such a transformation. A vector on the axis of rotation is an eigenvector for $M$ of eigenvalue $1$. Therefore $(M-I)$ annihilates such vectors, and $(M-I)$ has $0$ for one of its eigenvalues. From this, it follows that $(M-I)$ has determinant $0$.